# Mount read-write volume inside of read-only volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have two volumes: `repo` and `cache`. I want to mount `repo` read-only at `/repo` and I want to mount `cache` as read-write at `/repo/cache`. When the app writes to `/repo/cache`, I expect the writes to go to the `cache` volume, while the `/repo` volume is not changed; however, when I run `docker run -it -v repo:/repo:ro -v cache:/repo/cache alpine`, I get `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/cache/_data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f1dfff7f943921fd2da278d357bec88007d7fcb41eb9bc34fc0e728c459ad73/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f1dfff7f943921fd2da278d357bec88007d7fcb41eb9bc34fc0e728c459ad73/merged/repo/cache\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f1dfff7f943921fd2da278d357bec88007d7fcb41eb9bc34fc0e728c459ad73/merged/repo/cache: read-only file system\\\"\"": unknown.`

Is there a better way to achieve this result? I need the `repo` volume to be `ro` so the app doesn't write to it, and I need `cache` to be writable and mounted "inside" of `/repo` because that's where the app expects it (and I can't modify the app to look elsewhere).

Answer (score 4):

To mount your `cache` volume on `/repo/cache`, Docker would need to be able to create a directory `/repo/cache` inside the container. Since you have mounted the `repo` volume read-only, this isn't possible.

If you first create the mountpoint yourself:

```
docker run --rm -v repo:/repo alpine mkdir /repo/cache
```

Then you will be able to successfully mount `/repo/cache` despite `repo` being read-only:

```
bash-5.0$ docker run --rm -it -v repo:/repo:ro -v cache:/repo/cache alpine
/ # ls /repo
cache
```